# Как прокрутить HScrollBar в Panel (роликом мыши)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите, как прокрутить HScrollBar в Panel таким образом, чтобы при наведении мыши в Panel активировался HScrollBar и ролик мыши мог им управлять?

Растянутое состояние (для добавление чекбоксов)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сжатое состояние (какими должны быть размеры приложения)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Событие `MouseWheel`.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        panel1.MouseWheel += Panel1_MouseWheel;
    }

    private void Panel1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Delta > 0 && panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value < panel1.HorizontalScroll.Maximum)
        {
            panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value += 1;
        }
        if (e.Delta < 0 && panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value > panel1.HorizontalScroll.Minimum)
        {
            panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value -= 1;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не получается, выдает ошибку если вводить размер ширины `panel1` равную 200 (+= 200 и -= 200). Ошибка > Дополнительные сведения: Значение '-80' недопустимо для 'Value'. 'Value' должно лежать в диапазоне от 'minimum' до 'maximum'.

Comment: Не надо ничего менять, прямо этот код вставляйте, в нем есть проверка на  реальные размеры панели.